# Mine loop doesn't work in Javascript. I have to traverse loop to array and multiply by 2

Tags: javascript, loops

hey guys i have problem with my exercise:
"using a while loop, traverse the array and multiply each price by 2" i have this to now

```js
var prices = [10, 15, 25, 8, 4, 55, 99, 11, 15, 25, 5, 4, 65, 5, 10, 15, 7, 8, 4, 9, 100];
while (prices < 201) {
  console.log('This item costs', prices);
  prices * 2
}
```

I don't know where the error is?

Comment: var prices = [10, 15, 25, 8, 4, 55, 99, 11, 15, 25, 5, 4, 65, 5, 10, 15, 7, 8, 4, 9, 100];

while (prices < 201){
    console.log('This item costs', prices);
     prices*2
}

Comment: while (prices < 201)... you are comparing an array with an integer, please review https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison also you are doing it once and not for every item in the array

Comment: Hey, could you please explain the your intention behind doing "prices<201"?

Comment: Every price have to be multiply by 2. max price was 100. 100*2=200. 200<201 our max price is 200 thats why

Comment: I cant open this page from mozilla :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are just doing for one element. In array you have to access element with their index number. The logic for doing is that you have to loop till the end of the array and for each element have to multiply the price by 2. 
I have attached the code below with proper logic.

```js
 var prices = [10, 15, 25, 8, 4, 55, 99, 11, 15, 25, 5, 4, 65, 5, 10, 15, 7, 8, 4, 9, 100];
    var i=0;
    //loop to double price of each element in the array
    while (i < prices.length){
     prices[i]=prices[i]*2;
     i++; 
    }
   console.log(prices);
```